# Resample GeoTIFF in QGIS

Tags: qgis

WHat is the workflow to downsample a GeoTIFF.  These instructions, the Warp dialog displayed is not the same as shown in my current QGIS as there's no resolution settings?

https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2015/04/resampling-single-geotiff-image-in-qgis.html

Comment: Resolution (pixel size) is set with "Output file resolution in target georeferenced units".

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking on your GeoTiff, Export --> Save as... And there you can specify your new resolution (in the case of this screenshot, 10m, since my project is in UTM) and export to save as a new GeoTiff. Make sure to choose Rendered image if your Geotiff is an RGB one.

[image: Resampling to 10m]