# Downsampling GeoTIFF in QGIS using GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, geotiff-tiff, resampling

I need to downsample a GeoTIFF image. I have been trying to test this using a simple example like [image: GHI_clip] using the following r.samp.res dialog.
(I know I could also export the TIF file directly following [Resample GeoTIFF in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341468/resample-geotiff-in-qgis))

As I didn't know about the resolution unit I set east-west and north-south resolution to 5:

[image: r.resamp.rst]
Unfortunately I get only errors that indicate that temporal results are not available.
[image: Error Message]
Looking into the directory none of the expected files are available.

What am I doing wrong or is this a GRASS or QGIS error?

Here I add the GeoTIFF file (13kb) I am using so that everybody can try themself:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sh-8VvvGyq3Cs_ZCuYOHPLZvKdbXfHye/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: The log shows lots of "Raster map not found" errors. Can you set `GRASS GIS 7 region extent` and try again? (although it says it's optional......)

Comment: I set the GRASS GIS 7 region extent to the small sample TIFF I was using but still get the same error

Comment: In the screenshot you posted it seems that the original is in CRS 4326 (longitude latitude, with degree units). If that's true, and you set the resolution to 5, that would be 5 **degrees** , about 550 kilometers. Maybe that's the problem.
In any case, for resampling interpolation, you probably want to first reproject the raster to a local cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the large map unit. I tried a smaller resolution like 0.1 degree but it didn't work either. I also saved the layer in different metric coordinate systems like epsg6875, epsg102083 and epsg3004 but the same error keeps occurring.
I just added the GeoTIFF file in my original post so that everybody can try and see themself.

Comment: Using a resolution of 0.01 with the file you provided without reprojecting, it works perfectly, I get 6 output rasters.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why you don't use `Export` => `Save as` in the context menu, as for me it works fine:

[image] ====>
[image]

Comment: The grass plugin has a lot more options and should work as well. If it doesn't work and the reason is not a user's fault then a bug report needs to be filed. Do other people get the same error? Has anybody experience with GRASS and can try executing the commands directly in a shell and see if they show the same result?